# ACCESS: Exceed 255 character minimum

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2010

I have discovered that I am not pulling in all of the characters for some records from a relationship in one of my fields.

For one field, the query is only pulling the first 255 characters.

After some research, I found that changing the field type from Text to "Memo" allows for more characters in a field. Unfortuntely, when I run my query I then receive an error saying "Memo" cannot join (which makes sense since memo has the potential to join gigabites worth of data).

Is it possible to use a field with a Memo type in my query? I found that using "Left(blah.table,255) would be the inner join work around, but I seem to time out my query when I add this change.

A summary of the many comments below by a suggestion from guitarthrower:

Clarification #1: I do not have control on how I receive the data and the format I must export it in (bringing it into and out of Excel)

Clarification #2: The Query does exactly what I need accomplish for all field <255 characters (the majority). For the ~50 rows of data that are >255, I need to edit my query to capture all of it.

Clarification #3: Upon further analysis of my query, I am able to use a query similar to Allen Browne's concat function and I do have results that are >255 characters using this function in Access, but when I use this query with another one, Access truncates the results to =255 characters.

Clarification #4: I am using a combination of joining multiple columns together and a function "conc" that is similar to Allen Browne's function. This must be done because of the nature of table. The concate function is used to combine multiple rows of data into a single row. I have no control on how this data looks before Access (about 50,000 rows):

```
Before (Source 1):
1    joey    Cake
1    joey    apple
2    Pam     orange
2    Pam     pear

After (Group 1): 
1 Joey  Cake:apple
2 Pam   orange:pear
```

This Group 1 is then combined with another set of data from another source in a system I have zero control in.

```
Source 2: 
1 Joey water:paper
2 Pam  phone:tape


End result: 
1 Joey  Cake:Apple:water:paper
2 Pam   orange:pear:phone:tape
```

The "end result" is then truncated for some people.

However, the data from "Group 1" has some results that do exceed 255 and not trunacted in any way. Remember, Group 1 is formed from my "conc" function.

I have fully developed my queries to give me the "end result", but I need a way to exceed 255 characters as mentioned many times. I hope these clarifications are sufficient.

Comment: Why on earth are you joining on a field that could have more than 255 characters?

Comment: One question I need to ask is: why are you joining on huge text fields in the first place? That's very irregular for SQL joins and hints at poorly structured tables.

Comment: Please share your query and a sample of the output, and explain why you need more than 255 characters...

Comment: @mwolfe02 The end query is exported to excel and that file is uploaded into another service that requires a very specific format to manage a proprietary employee system I have no control over. To be absolutely clear: The format it is imported is one I do not have control over. If it was up to me, I would change the way the reporting field must be uploaded.

Comment: @Cory Please refer to my response to mwolfe2 for why I am joining 255+ fields. I am concatinating multiple different fields to create the reporting field. I also have ZERO control over the data I am given. The only aspect I have control in is how the database runs queries--which involves a series of inner joins and concat (a function similar to the one from Allen Browne). You are correct at the poorly structured tables--but to be absolutely clear I have NO control over how the tables come to me and I have NO control over the end product.

Comment: @guitarthrower Please refer to my above two comments for reasons why I have to join fields in excess of 255 characters. My final query contains proprietary Field names, but it is in the following type of format `SELECT [ALL].[Last name], [ALL].[First name], [ALL].PersNo AS [Password], [ALL].Qualifications AS [Group], 
FROM ([ALL] INNER JOIN [MED] ON [ALL].PersNo = [MED HR 1].PersNo) INNER JOIN [Contractor Badge & Shift] ON [ALL].PersNo = [Contractor Badge & Shift].Column4
ORDER BY [ALL].[Last name];
` The syntax may not read properly, but I had to remove some pieces of information.

Comment: @guitarthrower But, the general gist of the query is still captured. I do have a variety of queries that build up to this one too, but they are all in simialr formats (basically joining together pieces of related information to get my final output which is similar to `Last name | First Name | MED:blah blah:MED blah1 blah1:Med Blah Blah

Comment: As mentioned in my intial question, I have the right queries and final result/format I am looking for. I simply would like advice on how to utilize more than 255 characters. I have done other research on overflow columns which seems like a viable option, but I would like some help.

Comment: @redracer67 Please stop responding with comments. These clarifications would be better served as edits to your question. And you say that you have the correct query, but you state you are unable to get what you are looking for, which would lead me to believe that perhaps a change to your queries may be needed to get your desired result.

Comment: Re-reading all this now, and I have another question. You say you have no control over the table structure, but have mentioned that you can change the field type from Text to Memo. How are you able to do this?

Comment: Please, what hell is `HR 1` in `[MED HR 1]`?

Comment: @guitarthrower The data is pulled from an online database into excel and then imported into Access. I do not have write access to the excel data so I can edit in any way. But, I can change the data type once it is in Access. I'm working with a sample of the excel data for the database development purporses, but since the end product will be handed off to another individual, it is requested I do not change any data in excel. Or rather, the data must be imported into Access in the exact format it is exported from the online system. It is manipulated in Access and thenimported into another system

Comment: @LuisSiquot ...It is a table name. That is actually probably the only part that should make sense. This project has long been considered the "impossible problem" and I'm 99% there, I just need to get around the 255 character limit in Access.

Comment: re: "I am concatinating multiple different fields to create the reporting field." - Instead of doing the JOIN on the single concatenated field have you tried doing a multi-column JOIN on the constituent fields?

Answer (score -1):

I use memo fields all of the time. If your query isn't working, try using FIRST with the memo, if that is possible. That gets around some of the restrictions.